# Problem with a datalist event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, datalist

The DataList:

```
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="AllQuestionsResponded" 
                    GridLines="Horizontal" DataKeyField="ThreadsID" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="DataList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">'<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>'</asp:LinkButton>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

And the sql dataSource:

```
           <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllQuestionsResponded" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CP_AllQuestionsAnswered %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ThreadTitle, ThreadsID
FROM Threads 
WHERE ThreadsID IN (SELECT ThreadsID
FROM Comments
WHERE UsersID=@UserID)
" onselecting="AllQuestionAskedDataSource_Selecting">
```

The code behind event:

```
    protected void DataList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("AnswerQuestion.aspx?x=" + DataList2.DataKeyField + "&question=" + DataList2.SelectedValue + "&time=" + DateTime.Now);
}
```

The event never gets triggered!! no matter how many times I press the button link.. Why is that :( ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying CommandName for selection.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="Select" runat="server">'<%# Eval("ThreadTitle") %>'</asp:LinkButton>
```

Alternatively, you could use a ButtonColumn

```
<asp:BoundColumn    ButtonType="LinkButton"
                    HeaderText="ColumnHeader" 
                    DataField="LinkButton"
                    CommandName="Select" />
```

Comment: Thanks it works..but i cant pass the value selected.. It tells me that  DataList1.SelectedValue.ToString() is in the wrong format.it throws a Format Exception :(

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" command="Select" autopostback="True">
```